# How to get data into other class for preparing chart in react js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

How to call CsvRead.jsx file data into GoogleChart.jsx for preparing chart in React js.

GoogleChart.jsx is the parent class which has import statement of CsvRead.jsx
but unable to parse data from CsvRead.jsx into GoogleChart.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import ReactFileReader from 'react-file-reader';

export default class CsvRead extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  handleFiles = files => {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
    var csv = reader.result;
    var lines = csv.split("\n");
    var result = [];
    var headers=lines[0].split(",");
    for(var i=1;i<lines.length;i++){
      var obj = {};
      var currentline=lines[i].split(",");
      for(var j=0;j<headers.length;j++){
        obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
      }
      result.push(obj);
      }  
      //return result; //JavaScript object
      result= JSON.stringify(result); //JSON
    console.log(result);
  }
  reader.readAsText(files[0]);
}

  render() {
    return (
      <ReactFileReader handleFiles={this.handleFiles} fileTypes={'.csv'}>
        <button className='btn'>Upload</button>
      </ReactFileReader>
    );
  }
}
```

Second File GoogleChart.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { createHashHistory } from 'history';
import { Chart } from 'react-google-charts';
import CsvRead  from '../dynamic/CsvRead'

const customHistory = createHashHistory();

class GoogleChart extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
  super(props);
    this.state = {
      options: {
        title: 'Users Hours comparison',
        hAxis: { title: 'User'},
        vAxis: { title: 'Hours'},
        legend: 'none',
        axisTitlesPosition: 'out',
        'isStacked': true,
        colors: ['#0598d8', '#f97263'],
      },

      data : [
    ['User', 'workingHours', 'ExceptedWorkingHours'],
    ['user1', 500, 400],
    ['user2', 300, 200],
    ['user3', 1500, 650],
    ['user4', 1200, 470],
    ['user5', 1000, 700],
    ['user6', 500, 400],
    ['user7', 1300, 500],
    ['user8', 176, 55],
    ['user9', 310, 240],
    ['user10', 500, 400]
]
      // That should contain data from CsvRead.jsx
    };
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (      
      <div><CsvRead/>
      <Chart
        chartType="ColumnChart"
        data = { this.state.data }
        options={this.state.options}
        graph_id="ColumnChart"
        width="100%"
        height="400px"
        legend_toggle
      />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


function select(state) {
    return {
        users: state.users
    }
}

export default connect(select)(GoogleChart);
```

I have added all details let me know if you guys required anything else.Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific, which part exactly is giving you an error or w/e?

Comment: @user2073973 -  I have updated the question but data part on Googlechart.jsx should contain the returned value of CsvRead.jsx.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

https://pastebin.com/0QgZ8E3a

You have to transfer the result to the parent object using a callback.

```
<CsvRead onDone={this.onDone} />
```

And then in the CsvRead class:

```
this.props.onDone(result);
```

Comment: You have used `this.props.onDone(result);` but it returns undefined onDone function in CsvRead Class.

Comment: Have you added the onDone function in the GoogleChart component?

`onDone = (data) => {
    this.setState({data});
  }`

Comment: yes I did Please have a look : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46543376/data-is-not-fetched-in-this-state-data-on-googelchart-jsx

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, you're trying to get the data in `<CsvRead>` into `<GoogleChart>`. **IF** that's what you're trying to do, then you should create a function in `GoogleChart` to receive the data, and reference that function in `CsvRead`. Something Like this,

```js
class GoogleChart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.firstFunction = this.firstFunction.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      data: null,
    }
  }
  
  firstFunction(data) {
    this.setState({ data }); //save the data in the state (or whatever you want to do to it)
  }
  
  render() {
    return(
      <CsvRead someFunction={this.firstFunction} />
    );
  }
}


class CsvRead extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: 'whatever this can be',
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return(
      {/* This should work */}
      <Blahhh onClick={this.props.someFunction.bind(null, this.state.data)}/>

      {/* This should work as well */}
      <Blahhh onClick={this.props.someFunction(this.state.data)}/>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @ManishJakhode I just edited the code. You can try it again and let me know if it works or not.